# Transform upstream request query params using Lambda Authorizer outcome

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

**Is there a standard, supported way of transforming the request URL sent to the Gateway's upstream, using values determined by the Lambda Authorizer?**

In my AWS API Gateway, my resources use a Lambda "authorizer". The authorizer decrypts an authentication token carried by the request, and does partial authorization, before passing the request upstream.

My goal is to attach the decrypted authentication token to the upstream request, preferably as a request parameter, but a request header would also work if it must. I presume there should be a way to achieve this either in the authorizer step of my resource's "Method Request", or somehow in the "Integration Request" step of the resource.

For example, the [Using API Gateway Custom Authorizers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html#api-gateway-custom-authorizer-token-lambda-function-create) document demonstrates how to attach custom parameters to an authorization policy:

```js
// Optional output with custom properties of the String, Number or Boolean type.
authResponse.context = {
    "stringKey": "stringval",
    "numberKey": 123,
    "booleanKey": true
};
return authResponse;
```

This *seems* like the perfect interface for communicating between the Authorizer Lambda (of the Gateway resource's *Method Request*) and the URL transformation capabilities of the Gateway resource's *Integration Request*, but **I haven't found the documented way of accessing authorizer context data from the "Integration Request Parameters".**

[Mapping templates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/models-mappings.html) seem to solve this problem for transforming request payloads. How do I access custom auth response context for dynamic request parameters?

It seems possible to use a Lambda proxy integration in the "Integration Request" position, which would orchestrate its own transformed "passthrough," but this seems like a bit of preposterous reinvention inside of the Gateway architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is in the docs, it just requires a little bit of extrapolation.

The following table at ["Map Method Request Data to Integration Request Parameters"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/request-response-data-mappings.html#mapping-request-parameters) suggests that context values are available to Integration Request Parameters:

[image: The table at "Map Method Request Data to Integration Request Parameters" which suggests that context values are available to Integration Request Parameters]

Although the [linked context variable reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#context-variable-reference) is very specific to request mapping, under `$context.authorizer.property`:

> The stringified value of the specified key-value pair of the context
>   map returned from an API Gateway custom authorizer Lambda function.
>   For example, if the authorizer returns the following context map:
>
> `"context" : {   "key": "value",   "numKey": 1,   "boolKey": true }`
>
> calling `$context.authorizer.key` returns the "value" string, calling
>   `$context.authorizer.numKey` returns the "1" string, and calling
>   `$context.authorizer.boolKey` returns the "true" string.

Just add the name of the key from the custom values of your authorizer response context, like `context.authorizer.booleanKey`, in keeping with the example in the documentation:

[image: Screen shot, how to add context authorizer values as URL Query String parameters in resource Integration Request]

Keeping in mind that the "Test" function in the resource's "Method Execution" interface isn't a valid test of such a configuration, since the Method Request authorizer is not executed from the test interface. Test logs show that the authorizer context variable is not available:

`Mon Feb 05 14:54:37 UTC 2018 : Endpoint request URI: http://v.x.y.z/ping?standard_context_var_ex=vxyz&test=1`

To test, I had to deploy the API Gateway, tail my access logs and make a live request (which satisfies the authorizer.)